# Notepad++ Insert (paste) without replace the whole text

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way to insert the text from the right document to left without replacing the whole file?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN0kJ.png)

There are around 40,000 texts, So it would be difficult to copy-paste each line.

Comment: Have you tried `Merge files in one` plugin?

Comment: I think I would use a spreadsheet: insert first and second file as tabs in the spreadsheet, extend both tabs by a column with the linenumber. create a third empty tab, create a linenumber column, too. In the next column do a "if then else" : if linenumber has remainder 1 or 2 when devided by 3: take text from first tab, else take text from second tab .